# Table row to fill entire page

Tags: tables, tabularx, alignment

I am currently working on a table that I can print and take notes in. My main problem is, that I want the last row of a table to take up all the available space. Somehow like column 'X' works for the width of the table, but for rows and the height.
Is there any smart way of solving this problem?

My current solution is to just "guess" the available space and using a `\vspace*{}` to extend the row.

Another problem with my solution is the vertical alignment of the first column. As you can see the notes is pushed up a bit. Is there a way to preserve to vertical position of the text, or even better align the text vertically?

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|p{2.7cm}|X|p{0.5cm}|p{0.5cm}|p{0.5cm}|p{0.5cm}|}
\hline
Col 1 & Col 2 & a & b & c & d \\
\hline
Chapter 1 & Some Text & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4\\
\hline
Notes \vspace*{1cm} & \multicolumn{5}{c|}{}\\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What should the available space be in a documentclass which adapts the paper size to match the content?

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Oh I was working on a minimal example. I change it to article. My mistake

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Did you see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/34261/47927 ? I admit, that the solutions are without actual tabulars.

Comment: @JasperHabicht I just checked the link you provided. The second solution uses a table, but still specifies the height using `\parbox[l][.60\textheight]`. Making a table by hand using `multicols` doesn't seem the way to go.

Comment: The problem is that the cells in a table are `\hboxes` which don't know anything about the page height. The only way to solve this problem would be to measure the remaining space on the page, I fear. `\vfill` only works inside boxes with a fixed size (such as the page or a `\parbox`  or `minipage` of a distinct height).

Comment: @JasperHabicht How does the X-column work? Understand this type of column way overshoots my knowledge about latex, but eventually I want the same behavior just for rows.

Comment: The `X` column would calculate the width of the cell as something like `\textwidth - 2.7cm - 4 * 0.5cm - 2 * 5 * \tabcolsep`. As I said, you would need to measure the remaining space on the page (for example by subtracting the space the first rows need from `\textheight`).

Comment: Good to know. Calculating the height of all these rows doesn't seem as easy. I will look into some documentations, but I'm not very hopeful of coming up with a solution.

Comment: Please clarify if the `tabular`-like environment is supposed to take up the entire page, both height-wise and width-wise.

Comment: Yes, that is correct

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A solution using `nicematrix`, probably a bit complicated. It uses Ti*k*Z to measure the height of a row which is relatively easy, because the package adds Ti*k*Z coordinate to the cells. This way, you can calculate the height of the first rows and subtract this from `\textheight` to finally create a `\vcellfill` macro:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix, tikz}

% ===== code copied from Zarko
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
% =====

\newlength{\lastrowheight}
\newcommand{\getrowheight}[1]{%
    \tikz {
        \pgfmathparse{int(#1+1)} 
        \path (#1-|1);
        \pgfgetlastxy{\ax}{\ay}
        \path (\pgfmathresult-|1);
        \pgfgetlastxy{\bx}{\by}
        \pgfmathsetlength{\global\lastrowheight}{abs(\by-\ay)}
    }%
}

\newlength{\rowsheight}
\newcommand{\addtorowsheight}[1]{%
    \getrowheight{#1}\global\addtolength{\rowsheight}{\lastrowheight}%
}

% ===== idea copied from John Kormylo
\newcommand{\vcellfill}{%
    \rule[\dimexpr\arraystretch\ht\strutbox-\textheight+\rowsheight\relax]%
        {0pt}{\dimexpr\textheight-\rowsheight\relax}%
}
% =====

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{NiceTabular}{ p{2.7cm} X p{0.5cm} p{0.5cm} p{0.5cm} p{0.5cm} }[hvlines]
\CodeBefore
    % we want the height of the first two rows
    \addtorowsheight{1}\addtorowsheight{2}
\Body
Col 1 & Col 2 & a & b & c & d  \\
Chapter 1 & Some Text \newline more text & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
Notes & \multicolumn{5}{c|}{\vcellfill} \\
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks to Zarko for the idea of coloring the frame, thanks to John Kormylo for the idea of using a `\rule`.

Answer (score 4):

you could combine with tcolorbox and draw some of the lines with overlay (here the dotted line):

```
\documentclass[addpoints,12pt,a4paper,dvipsnames]{exam}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[top=2cm, bottom=2cm, left=2.5cm, right=2.5cm, headsep=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\newtcolorbox{mynotes}
 {height fill=true,
  enhanced,colback=white,
  size=tight,
  sharp corners,
  overlay={\draw[dotted]([xshift=2.7cm+2\tabcolsep]frame.north west)--([xshift=2.7cm+2\tabcolsep]frame.south west);}}


\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}

\begin{mynotes}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{p{2.7cm}X|p{0.5cm}|p{0.5cm}|p{0.5cm}|p{0.5cm}}
Col 1 & Col 2 & a & b & c & d \\
\hline
Chapter 1 & Some Text & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4\\
\hline
Notes   \\

\end{tabularx}
\end{mynotes}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

This uses a savebox to measure the tabular without the notes, then uses a strut (`\ruie{0pt}{...}`) instead of `\vspace`.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{showframe}

\newlength{\goodguess}

%\def\arraystretch{2}

\begin{document}

\par% \pagetotal refeshed between paragraphs, duplicate \par is ignored
\ifdim\pagegoal=\maxdimen
  \setlength{\goodguess}{\textheight}%
\else
  \setlength{\goodguess}{\dimexpr \pagegoal-\pagetotal}%
\fi
\sbox0{\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|p{2.7cm}|X|p{0.5cm}|p{0.5cm}|p{0.5cm}|p{0.5cm}|}
\hline
Col 1 & Col 2 & a & b & c & d \\
\hline
Chapter 1 & Some Text & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4\\
\hline
\end{tabularx}}% measure height
\setlength{\goodguess}{\dimexpr \goodguess-\ht0-\dp0}%

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|p{2.7cm}|X|p{0.5cm}|p{0.5cm}|p{0.5cm}|p{0.5cm}|}
\hline
Col 1 & Col 2 & a & b & c & d \\
\hline
Chapter 1 & Some Text & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4\\
\hline
Notes & \multicolumn{5}{c|}{\rule[\dimexpr \arraystretch\ht\strutbox-\goodguess]{0pt}{\goodguess}}\\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

**Edit:**
After editing of question, I guess that you after the following:

[image]

(red lines show page layout)

Is this what you after (apparently I didn't understood your problem=?

For above table I use `tabularray` package (instead of `tabular`) since with it is simpler to define multicolumn cell as well its height:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{geometry}
%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}

\bigskip
\begin{tblr}{hlines, vlines,
             colspec = {Q[l, wd=27mm] X[l] *{4}{Q[l, wd=5mm]}},
             row{Z}  = {\dimexpr\textheight-3\baselineskip}, % determine row height
             hspan=minimal
             }
Col 1       & Col 2     & a & b & c & d     \\
Chapter 1   & Some Text & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4     \\
Notes       & \SetCell[c=5]{j}  \lipsum[66]   % multicolumn cell, adjusted content over all spanned columns, \lipsum is just to demonstrate how it works
                        &   &   &   &       \\
\end{tblr}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I am actually not! I want the cell containing the lipsum to be completely empty. And to add to the problem, the cell should have the same height as `\hfill` would provide.

Comment: +1 @LukasKöhl or other people. Use the down vote button, if the answer is spam or directly hurtful for other people looking for answers. If you find that the answer is not helping you, you could choose not upvote or upvote anyway to show support. -AND edit your question to make it clear what you are looking for.

Comment: Just wanted to clarify that I didn't down vote the answer. Zarko seems like a knowledgeable person, who didn't quite get the problem. He still might come back to his own answer and edit it.

Comment: @LukasKöhl, sorry, than your question is misleading or at least unclear. `\lipsum[66]` Is just dummy text filer which demonstrate that content of the multicolumn cell can occupy the whole cell.  In you use you should remove package `lipsum` and command `\lipsum]66]`. It seems that you not familiar with intention of packages `lipsum` or `blindtext` ...

Comment: @Zarko I am familiar with these packages. The key point is, that I don't want **any** text inside the cell, but the cell should still take up the entire page. Removing lispum in your answer still makes the cell shrink, which is not the behaviour I am looking for. My intention is, to print the table and fill it by hand.

Comment: @LukasKöhl, after your edit of question become clear what you after. See edited answer ()will appear soon)